# Get Vibrant.js swatches using jsdom or Canvas for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, canvas, jsdom

I have a process to get images in node.js using either jsdom or Canvas. During the download process, I want to extract swatches using Vibrant.js in the backend. Neither of my code below works.

Using **jsdom**

```
const Vibrant = require('node-vibrant');
const request = require('request');

var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;
var window = jsdom().defaultView;
var document = jsdom('<html><body></body></html>', {
  features: {
    FetchExternalResources : ['img']
  }
});

var imgDom = document.createElement("img");

imgDom.onload = function() {
    console.log('onload triggered');
    // var imgData = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAADCAIAAAA7ljmRAAAAGElEQVQIW2P4DwcMDAxAfBvMAhEQMYgcACEHG8ELxtbPAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC';
    // var imgData = imgDom.replace(/^data:image\/gif;base64,/, "")
    // var binaryData =  new Buffer(imageData, 'base64').toString('binary');

    request.get(imgDom.src, function(err, res, body) {  
        console.log(body.length);

        // Spit out a bunch of base64 code
        let v = new Vibrant(new Buffer(body, 'binary').toString('base64'));
        // Error image.load not found
        // let v = new Vibrant(new Buffer(body, 'binary').toString('base64'), {ImageClass: window.Image});


        // Error: Path must be a string without null bytes
        // let v = new Vibrant(new Buffer(body, 'base64').toString('binary'));

        // v.getPalette().then((palette) => console.log(palette));
        var swatches = v.swatches();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(swatches));
        for (var swatch in swatches)
            if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch])
                console.log(swatch, swatches[swatch].getHex())
    });

}

imgDom.src = 'https://unsplash.it/200';


// imgDom.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAADCAIAAAA7ljmRAAAAGElEQVQIW2P4DwcMDAxAfBvMAhEQMYgcACEHG8ELxtbPAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC';
```

Using **Canvas**

```
const Vibrant = require('node-vibrant');
const request = require('request');
const Canvas = require('canvas-prebuilt');
const Image = Canvas.Image;

var imgDom = new Image;

imgDom.onload = function() {
    console.log('onload triggered');
  let v = new Vibrant(imgDom, {ImageClass: Canvas.Image});
  v.getPalette().then((palette) => console.log(palette));    
};

request.get('https://unsplash.it/200', function(err, res, body) {  
    console.log(body.length);

    imgDom.src = new Buffer(body);
    // imgDom.src = new Buffer(body, 'binary').toString('base64');
    // imgDom.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAADCAIAAAA7ljmRAAAAGElEQVQIW2P4DwcMDAxAfBvMAhEQMYgcACEHG8ELxtbPAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC';

});
```

I could use URL in Vibrant.js but that's another http GET using Bluebird and I need to avoid calling the network to download again.

I think Vibrant.js has a hard time to understand the Image object in Node.js.

**What is the workaround here so that I can pass proper Image class to Vibrant.js?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Building the buffer correctly

`encoding:null` **returns buffers instead of strings**.
(*strings gives you unusably garbled data*)

```
const Vibrant = require('node-vibrant');
const request = require('request').defaults({encoding:null});

doRequest('https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4TSy.jpg')
function doRequest(url){
  request.get(url, function(err, res, body) {
    if(err)throw err
      //Here is the magic
      const buffer = new Buffer(body)
      console.log(buffer)
      let v = new Vibrant(buffer)
      v.getPalette().then((palette) => console.log(palette))
  })
}
```

---

## Extra : Using JIMP

The Vibrant constructor's `imagePath` arg is directly passed to the abstract Image constructor (`NodeImage` in the NodeJS environment and `NodeImage` uses [Jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp))

```
/*:USING JIMP:*/
doJimpRequest('https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4TSy.jpg')
const Jimp = require('jimp')
function doJimpRequest(url){
  Jimp.read(url, function (err, image) {
    if(err)throw err
    image.getBuffer(Jimp.AUTO,function(err, buffer){
      console.log(buffer)
      let v = new Vibrant(buffer)
      v.getPalette().then((palette) => console.log(palette))
    })
  });
}
```